# Sequence of largest roots of Hermite polynomials

Tags: polynomials, orthogonal-polynomials, hermite-polynomials

Let's denote with $\{x_n\}_{n\in N}$ the sequence of the largest root of the (statistical) [Hermite polynomial $h_n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Explicit_expression). Much is known about upper and lower bounds of the $x_n$, see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2525094/proving-that-all-the-real-roots-of-hermite-polynomials-are-in-sqrt4n1-s). Clearly, the sequence is monotonically increasing (due to the [interlacing property](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4429717/interlacing-properties-of-zeros-of-orthogonal-polynomials)). Studying the numerical values
\begin{eqnarray}
x_1&=&0\\
x_2&=&1\\
x_3&=&1.7320\ldots\\
x_4&=&2.3344\ldots\\
x_5&=&2.8569\ldots\\
\end{eqnarray}
one can observe that the difference $x_{n+1}-x_n$ is monotonically **decreasing** which I like to prove. A promising approach seems to be the via the facts
$$h_n''-xh_n'+nh_n=0\quad \text{and}\quad h_n'=nh_{n-1},$$
but I failed. Help would be welcome!

Answer (score 2):

You wish to show that the sequence of largest positive zeros form a concave sequence.  This (and much more) is shown in the paper [*Inequalities and monotonicity properties for zeros of Hermite functions*](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0308210500027463) by Á. Elbert and M. E. Muldoon. See especially the end of Section $7$.

Comment: Thanks for the source. Unfortunatelly, the paper is not public. Is it possible to sketch the main idea of the proof or is it to profound?

Comment: It is highly non-trivial. They consider a continuous version $H_\lambda(x)$ of $H_n(x)$ and show that if $x_\lambda$ is any zero then $x'_\lambda$ is completely monotonic. In particular they use $$
\frac{{{\rm d}x_\lambda  }}{{{\rm d}\lambda }} = \sqrt {\frac{\pi }{2}} \int_0^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - (2\lambda  + 1)t} {\rm e}^{x_\lambda ^2 \tanh t} {\mathop{\rm erfc}\nolimits} (x_\lambda  \sqrt {\tanh t} )\frac{{{\rm d}t}}{{\sqrt {\sinh (2t)} }}} .
$$